# How do I wire a remote fan switch and still be able to use wall switches?

Tags: wiring

I have 2 wall switches. 4 wires coming out of the ceiling (black-hot, red-hot, white-common, bare- ground), [this ceiling fan and remote](https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/e1/e10c9080-c433-4ee3-97e4-7d0d6c820803.pdf) (PDF of instructions). How do I wire them and still be able to use wall switches and remote?

I'd like to be able to turn off the light/fan switches individually but also utilize the remote when each switch is on. So 1 switch provides power to the lights and the other to the fan.

Remote unit has Black and White inputs and Black, White, Blue (bottom light) and Orange (top light) outputs to fan/light fixture.

Is this possible or do I just cap the red and have a master switch and a useless switch?

Comment: What make and model of remote are you looking at? Would you be interested in taking it back for a different remote? Is the existing fan wall switch a double-switch with two switches on the same *yoke*, or two separate switches on two separate yokes?

Comment: The remote is what came with the fan. 1 yoke for red and 1 for black. PDF for fan and remote are here: https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/e1/e10c9080-c433-4ee3-97e4-7d0d6c820803.pdf

Comment: The design of the remote is for installation to replace a light controlled by a single wall switch. The receiver only has one hot input so you can not use both wall switches with this remote. As you anticipated you would only connect one of the switched hots and put a wire nut on the other. You would usually leave the connected switch in the ON position. The remote on my Hunter fan has a holder that mounts over the switch being used but allows access to the switch if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

### Get a different remote and receiver

If you want a remote and receiver that will play nicely with having light switches in the wall that work, you'll need to set what came with your fan aside and get something else instead.  My suggestion would be to get a Lutron Caseta fan controller and matching dimmer; they install instead of your existing wall switches and provide both wall and remote control.

Comment: Well done! I knew somebody built something like that.